# Displaying real time data from Mongo database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, websocket, socket.io, real-time

I've been thinking about how to make a weather real-time web application using nodejs/mongodb.
I want to display weather data from database every time a new document is added, should I use socket.io or something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
you can use socket.io for that,
as soon as data get inserted you will get a callback and through socket listner you can show or send to client side.
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the script inserting in database is a python script

Comment: hmm,unfortunatly mongodb doesn't have callback like Postgres .
to show data in real time you can use socket programming in python as well.
if you are using python for database queries and node.js for web platform,you can use socket.io in node and zeroRPC to communicate with python backend.

hope it helps :)